# User Agent String - provide as variable

Tags: user-agent, browser-detection

I need to find the user agent string, which it looks like UserAgentSTring.com does for me but I need to store that so I can pass it to the server side.  I am not sure how to accomplish this?

The API docs say this:
You can send a ua string as post or get request (form field or in the query string).
Use 'uas' as parameter name:

?uas=Opera/9.70%20(Linux%20i686%20;%20U;%20en-us)%20Presto/2.2.0

this will automatically parse the string. To get some data you have to add one more parameter:

But if I put that line in my source code, in the header of my page how will the server side recognize it?  Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can just use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] but if that is not what you are looking for, look into HTML forms. Putting it in the header of your source code will do nothing for the server if it is not in PHP/ASP

Answer (score 0):

Server-side approach with PHP:

```
<html>
<body>
Hi! You're using:

<?php
$jsonText = file_get_contents("http://useragentstring.com/?getJSON=all&uas=" + urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
$obj = json_decode($jsonText, true);
echo $obj['agent_name'] . " " . $obj['agent_version'] . " on " . $obj['os_name'];
?>

Lol.
</body>
</html>
```

A client-side approach with Javascript is a bit more complex and you are better off not using useragentstring.com for this but using the browser's built-in mechanisms, like [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).